# C# WPF - Binding value of dictionary as value of parent dictionay

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, radgridview

I'm using RadGridView in WPF. For his ItemsSource, I'm using this :

```
Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<int, double>>
```

Because this is the best way that I've found.
I create Columns dynamicaly. For the values binding, I did it :

```
colonneDate.DataMemberBinding = new Binding("key");
colonneVariable.DataMemberBinding = new Binding(string.Format("value[{0}].value", v.Id));
```

But the second one doesn't work (there is an empty result). I don't know how I can get the value of the value.

Can you help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: Hi Will, thank you for your answer.
I thought to use a custom class but there is will have too much rows because for one same date I have differents couples ID/Value.
This is for what I used Dictionnary in Dictionnary.

So, I searched an other way, and I will go to use DataTable as ItemsSource.  I inversed the DataTable columns and pushed it in RadGridView. The problem is by-passed.

Comment: So I have an other question : if i'm using a list and a custom class, the ItemsSource will be the list of custom class. 
e.g :
`"01/05/2014 - 1 - 12.5"
"01/05/2014 - 2 - 15"
"01/05/2014 - 3 - 1.5"`

How I can distinct items by date and display it by ID (second property) ?
Actually, i'm using a DataTable which is inversed in pivot.

Answer (score 0):

var binding = new Binding

{
    Path = new PropertyPath("DoubleValue"),

```
StringFormat = "{0:F1}"
```

};

textBlock.DataContext = viewModel;

textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);

Comment: Hi,

It's not working, but why you are using textBlock ? I'm setting GridViewDataColumn. 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I by-passed my problem :

To replace my Dictionary, I'm using a data table (like I said in a commentary). I inversed this DataTable with a method to have the wanted result.
After this, I'm using a DataGrid (replace RadGridView). ItemsSource is my DataTable, and the columns and rows are auto generated.

I hope this help.